# Document folder iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, nsfilemanager

How is possible to find quickly the document folder (in the mac) of an App when I'm using the simulator? When I need to explore the document folder during the simulation of the App now I use a variable of the App to find the document folder path and I read the path during the debug (using a variable) but I think is not the best solution.

Comment: Try the SimulatorManager. It's a Mac app that display an icon in the task bar with all simulator devices in the menu and allow you to browse apps document sandbox installed on each simulator. [http://tue-savvy.github.io](http://tue-savvy.github.io)

Comment: If you're developing only one app then there is only one folder beyond ~Libraries/Application Support/iPhoneSimulator (I have to check the path).

Comment: the path seems doesn't exist..

Comment: But the App is compatible only with XCode 6 and I use XCode7...

Comment: It works for me on XCode 7 / El capitan. You need to compile and install it.

Comment: Yes I'm trying it... it seems more easy than the plugin...

Comment: Yes it works correctly ... is a little bit slow at opening but it works.. thanks!

Comment: Try `~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhoneSimulator`

Comment: nothing to do.. the path doesn't exist. I solved using the mac App SimulationManager. Thanks anyway

Comment: See `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications` when you're developing for 7.1. When you're developing for 8.0 then check for 8.0. When you change to a directory, you can check for other dirs available by pressing `~/Library/App<tab>`.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Set and hit a breakpoint in the app, and write the following in the Xcode Console (next to the Variables View):

```
po NSHomeDirectory()
```

Then in Finder hit Shift+CMD+G, paste the path returned above without the quotation marks and hit enter.

Comment: This throws a compiler error for me; adjusting it to `var homeDir = NSHomeDirecotry; print(homeDir)` (or examining the value of homeDir at a break point) works though.

Comment: @AlexHall This answer says to write this command **in the console** while paused at a break point. I misread it at first too and thought it meant to put this command in your code.

Answer (score 28):

Open up Terminal.app and run:

```
xcrun simctl get_app_container booted [app identifier] data
```

You can even setup an alias to change to the directory, like:

```
alias cdmyapp='cd $(xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.mycompany.myapp data)'
```

Comment: I like the alias idea! But this is just the bundle folder, not the Documents folder.

Comment: This is awesome. May I know where can I get the list of other such functions (e.g get_app_container)? I'm basically looking to fetch Documents Directory from command line. Any Help?

Comment: This returns the .app bundle not the documents/data directory as the question asks

Comment: Great answer, in the modern Xcode environment I think this is probably the fastest way.

Comment: cd $(xcrun simctl get_app_container booted [app identifier] data) to get to the documents folder

Comment: `open $(xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.guidebook.guidebook data)/Documents` to open de documents folder. Notice `data` and `/Documents`.

Answer (score 6):

I have 2 solution

- [Simpholders](https://simpholders.com) or free and open source alternative [OpenSim](https://github.com/luosheng/OpenSim)
- A simple script that opens the finder window with the recently launched application on the iOS simulator

> deviceId=$(xcrun simctl list devices | grep Booted | sed -n
>   's/^.*([A-F0-9]{8}-([A-F0-9]{4}-){3}[A-F0-9]{12}).*$/\1/p')
>   applicationFolder=~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$deviceId/data/Containers/Data/Application/
>   applicationFolder=$applicationFolder$(ls -Art $applicationFolder |
>   tail -n 1) 
>   open $applicationFolder

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ZSH, you could try this script.
https://gist.github.com/nickcheng/cbc0717d2c9f79613cf2c042503b5422